# Is it possible to make a transformer with an input @ 120V/15A and get an output of 240V/15A?

Tags: transformer

Thank you for answering everyone. (I tried answering individually, but it’s not intuitive for me, so this is my answer.)

With my basic understanding of transformers I understand that it’s possible to get 240V/7.5A using my input referenced above, but I’m wondering if there’s a possibility of using another transformer or device to also increase the amperage back to 15A without decreasing the voltage back to 120V?

If so, what type of transformer(s) is/are needed?

Thanks!

Comment: Why stop there? Why not zero Watts input and infinite Watts output?

Comment: If I ever find one of those, I'm keeping it for myself.

Comment: The top part of the form is a short title. The bottom part is the question in full.

Comment: The title is supposed to give a summary of the topic in the question. You don't put greetings or "thanks" in a title.

Comment: Try and keep the sarcasm down for new users. Thanks

Comment: Basically you are asking us: how to create energy ... If we knew, we would be winning Nobel.

Answer (score 6):

No, not possible. You can't have a transformer that provides out double the power you put in.

Comment: Justme, it’s not possible with multiple transformers either?

Comment: No, not possible. Transformers only convert power you put into them and in an ideal world you get out exactly the same amount of power you put into it, so they are not able to just suddenly generate more power out that what is put in. In real world there are always losses, so you get somewhat less power out than you put in and the losses cause the tranformer to heat up.

Comment: @MikeJameson It's possible (but tricky and probably not code-compliant) to put in **two times** 120V 15A - so 30A total, but on two separate 15A connections - and get 240V 15A. Perhaps you were thinking of that?

Comment: Thank you Justme.

Comment: That would basically work for what I want, but if I were able to do that, I wouldn’t mind getting 240V/30A instead of the 240V/15A. Thanks user253751.

Answer (score 4):

The issue you're overlooking isn't voltage or current by themselves, but *power*.

Recall that Power = Volts * Amps. So we have:

- 120V at 15A is 1800W
- 240V at 15A is 3600W

So to supply 240V at 15A, you will need 120V at **30A** on the input side to get the 3600W on the output.

You could in theory use two 1:1 transformers and achieve that, as below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJD7Qr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've omitted finer details about earthing and grounding, or providing a neutral on the secondary. If your load doesn't need a neutral, the 'center tap' should be grounded. If your load does need a neutral, then that center tap should be provided a neutral feed back to the panel.

If you're unsure about any of this, consult an electrician. Even if you aren't, do it anyway for your own (and your insurance company's) peace of mind.

Comment: Thanks hacktastical.  I wonder if anyone has tried this in practice and has been successful?

Comment: It's basically what a 120-to 240V converter does. The challenge in your question is the power you're asking for is kind of big. 15A is the max for a normal 120V plug, and your requirement is for 30A to make 15A at 240V. Really, if this is something you need, consult an electrician. You may find that it would make more sense to install a 240V feed back to your panel than to use a transformer.

Comment: Thanks hacktastical for explaining this so clearly. I’ve learned more here than many hours searching Google. 

Could I buy a converter that does this? Do you have any idea of the dimensions of a converter that would do this? 

My load requires a North American 240V plug, so I don’t think it would require a neutral because the load would need each supply lead at 120V, but I believe it should be grounded.

Comment: I think at this point I would really recommend that you consult an electrician. They can look at what kind of appliance you’re intending to run and determine the best solution. You may find that it costs less to install a 240 V 15 amp feed directly from your panel compared to installing a 120 V 30 amp feed plus a transformer

Comment: Thank you @hacktastical.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to make a transformer with an input @ 120V/15A and get an output of 240V/15A?

No.

You can't get more out that you put in. You can't even break even.

But there is a trick.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGc2BK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Series connecting the transformer secondary with the mains will boost the secondary voltage to 240 V while maintaining 15 A subject to a capable supply.*

How it works:

- Since the bottom secondary winding of XFMR1 is connected to mains it will measure 120 V AC with respect to N.
- XFMR1's secondary is rated at 120 V and this will be added to the 120 V giving 240 V.
- 120 V × 15 A = 1800 VA (or W if the load is resistive) will be supplied by the mains (when the appropriate load is connected). Another 1800 W will be supplied by the mains through the transformer.
- Total mains consumption will be 120 V × 30 A = 1800 VA + transformer losses.
- Total output will be 240 V × 15 A = 3600 VA.

You will still need a 120 V supply capable of 30 A.

Comment: The issue with using the hot leg like that is that the input has to have clearly identified hot and neutral lines. The OP hasn't provided enough information to determine that.

Comment: If L and N are reversed the output would be 120 - 0 - 120. We have no context for the question so I can't go any further in that regard and the user hasn't given any location in the question or his user profile.

Comment: The bigger issue is the 30A feed required, which is unusual. Much easier to run a 240V feed from the panel instead. Either way, it's electrician time.

Comment: Aka an autotransformer.

Comment: @brhans, maybe, but it's not sold as an autotransformer which would only have one winding - at least on any I've seen.

Comment: "Figure 1. Series connecting the transformer secondary with the mains will *boost the secondary voltage and power*." I don't think so.

Comment: @hacktastical, I've clarified the wording slightly to be more clear: "*Series connecting the transformer secondary with the mains will boost the secondary voltage and total power available at 240 V.*" I haven't changed the principle of operation though. If you don't think this will work can you explain why? It is, as brhans commented, the principle of operation of an autotransformer.

Comment: It won't boost 'total power' so that caption is a problem, still. As far as the safety aspect, not knowing which secondary lead is *actually* neutral is also problem if the load is split-feed (say, an old dryer that shares neutral and ground on a 3-prong plug.) Such a load could have its chassis at 120V.

Comment: Thank you Transistor for the explanation and circuit schematic.  That’s the problem, I don’t have a 120V/30A supply.

Comment: @hacktastical, I thought I had covered it well enough in the *How it works* section. Another edit. How does it look now. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome, @Mike, but were you *really* hoping you could get more out than you put in? The laws of conservation of energy are very strict. Note, I have no idea what you intend to do with this information. I'm just explaining how a transformer *could* be used in this situation when complying with local electrical regulations.

Comment: @Transistor, I was really hoping that it would be possible through one or more transformers or any other electrical device to get what I want, 120V/15A supply to 240V/15A or more Amps,  in as small of a footprint as possible. And since I know very little about electricity, transformers or other electrical devices, I was hoping anyone, like you all, who have a much better understanding of electricity could help me figure out a possibility or knew of an existing solution.

Comment: Sorry to bring the bad news, @Mike.

Comment: No worries @Transistor. Thanks.